# How do I perform 2 actions with 1 submit button?

Tags: php, forms, post, action, mailchimp

My form has 1 submit button but needs to perform 2 actions. There are plenty of posts like this, except this issue has 2 different types of actions.
The first is to post to a .php file, and the second action needs to POST to MailChimp.

For instance, here is the form:

```
<form id="form-signup_v1" name="form-signup_v1" method="POST" action="http://mydomain.us10.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post">
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="fadf23525acar3fad">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3234davca4er">

            <input id="MERGE0"
                   name="MERGE0"
                   placeholder="My Email Address"
                   type="text"
                   data-validation="[EMAIL]">

<button class='buttonmain' id="buttoned" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Ideally, I'd like this form to have action="login.php" and then also somehow POST to `http://mydomain.us10.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post` including the required fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="fadf23525acar3fad">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3234davca4er">
```

How do I make the 1 submit button perform these 2 actions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it have to be in the specific order you described? First submit the form to login.php then send the POST request?

Comment: The form is simply a front end to the php logic. What have you tried in the php logic?

Comment: @ Diego, perhaps the POST request should be first, because action="login.php" would redirect the page and perhaps interfere with the POST request? I need *both* actions to definitely occur. @ James, are you asking what I've included in my login.php that addresses the MailChimp POST request issue? Nothing. I've found php that uses "include" but that seems to only run additional .php files. I need to POST to MailChimp while also including the "hidden" field values I posted above. How do I do this in php, or any way?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by adding some additional PHP code into my login.php file. I used cURL [by following this tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html). Hopefully it helps someone

Comment: I was going to suggest cURL but you beat me to it. Huzzah!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data to the login script first and then redirect to the other script after executing the first script, then you can send the data needed on the second script using GET parameters on the url. You can use a `header:location` for this... but have you consider doing those actions on the same script?

Comment: To be honest I'm super new to php and don't really know yet how to implement GET parameters or write proper headers. Perhaps performing both actions on the same script would be better? It sounds like a cleaner solution. I'd love an example or link if you could. Thanks so much